# Remotely Managing 5 - 10 Intranet PC's

Tags: windows, networking

I was thinking a VPN coupled with installing VNC software on client workstations. How do you remotely manage PC's for the small business's you support? Windows XP, Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Our IT guy lives in NZ, and our office is in Australia. [LogMeIn](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https://secure.logmein.com/au/&ei=cGeQUMzeHoWhigeu2YGQAg&usg=AFQjCNFs1WswT-VxXiSw0pVse1AWcc6dkQ&sig2=OFDWTeny__SJhn5wGl4iNA) is a very admirable solution, even if it is just the free version. It lets you log in via any browser. Best part is you just install the client on the pc's you need to monitor and register with your account.

If you need some more power behind it, the Pro version offers a lot of fine tuning tools, and monitoring capability. You get a 30 day trial for each client for you to play around with before it reverts back to free.

You could open ports, or VPN through and use an RDP/VNC client, but this opens up security holes, can be complicated, and is frankly uneccisary.

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn and TeamViewer are both good but if you're looking to avoid having to go through the internet (which LogMeIn and TeamViewer both do, IIRC), [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads.html) server is by far the best VNC server I've used.  Works well with TightVNC or other VNC clients.